# Date on x axis iphone using core plot

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-plot

I want to show data on x-axis on CPXYPlotSpace. I have seen doing so on mac using something like that but it does not work on iphone so any suggestion or i have to do it manually.

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
dateFormatter.dateStyle = kCFDateFormatterShortStyle;
CPTimeFormatter *timeFormatter = [[[CPTimeFormatter alloc] initWithDateFormatter:dateFormatter] autorelease];
timeFormatter.referenceDate = refDate;
x.labelFormatter = timeFormatter;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget to set intervalLength

```
    NSTimeInterval oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60;
x.majorIntervalLength = CPDecimalFromFloat(oneDay);
y.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPDecimalFromFloat(oneDay);
```

Comment: i use  `NSTimeInterval oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60;
    plotSpace.xRange = [CPPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPDecimalFromString(@"20/6/2011") length:CPDecimalFromFloat(oneDay*5.0f)];`